# In crystal report main report view print one page but system prints two pages

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In CrystalReport main report view print one page but system prints two pages

```
ReportDocument myDataReport = new ReportDocument();
myDataReport.Load(@"C:***\WindowsFormsApplication_Test\CrystalReport1.rpt");

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```